# Struct and bitfield strange behaviour

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, struct, bit-fields

I am trying to modify bitfields in register. Here is my struct with bitfields defined:

```
struct GROUP_tag
{
    ...
    union
    {
        uint32_t R;
        struct
        {
            uint64_t bitfield1:10;
            uint64_t bitfield2:10;
            uint64_t bitfield3:3;
            uint64_t bitfield4:1;
        } __attribute__((packed)) B;
    } __attribute__((aligned(4))) myRegister;
    ...
}

#define GROUP (*(volatile struct GROUP_tag *) 0x400FE000)
```

When I use the following line:

```
GROUP.myRegister.B.bitfield1 = 0x60;
```

it doesn't change only bitfield1, but bitfield2 as well. The register has value `0x00006060`.

Code gets compiled to the following assembly code:

```
ldr r3,[pc,#005C]
add r3,r3,#00000160
ldrb r2,[r3,#00]
mov r2,#00
orr r2,#00000060
strb r2,[r3,#00]
ldrb r2,[r3,#01]
bic r2,r2,#00000003
strb r2,[r3,#01]
```

If I try with direct register manipulation:

```
int volatile * reg = (int *) 0x400FE160;
*reg = 0x60
```

the value of register is `0x00000060`.

I am using GCC compiler.

Why is the value duplicated when I use struct and bitfields?

**EDIT**

I found another strange behaviour:

```
GROUP.myRegister.R = 0x12345678; // value of register is 0x00021212
*reg = 0x12345678; // value of register is 0x0004567, this is correct (I am programming microcontroller and some bits in register can't be changed)
```

My approach to change register value (with struct and bitfield) gets compiled to:

```
ldr r3,[pc,#00B4]
ldrb r2,[r3,#0160]
mov r2,#00
orr r2,#00000078
strb r2,[r3,#0160]
ldrb r2,[r3,#0160]
mov r2,#00
orr r2,#00000056
strb r2,[r3,#0161]
ldrb r2,[r3,#0162]
mov r2,#00
orr r2,#00000034
strb r2,[r3,#0162]
ldrb r2,[r3,#0163]
mov r2,#00
orr r2,#00000012
strb r2,[r3,#0163]
```

Comment: *Probably* unrelated (your code compiles, does it?), but `register` is a keyword in C, so you shouldn't ever use it as name.

Comment: I renamed some variables in my code and forgot that register is a keyword. I edited the question. My code compiles.

Comment: What happens if you try `GROUP.myRegister.B.bitfield2 = 0x60;` ? Does bitfield1 also change ?

Comment: It produces very strange result. The value of register becomes `0x00818181`.

Comment: @Mark Not that strange, `0x8181` is pretty close to `0x6060` left-shifted twice...

Comment: Oh okay, you are right. Any idea why this left shift happens?

Comment: The assembly code makes sense. The manipulation of the second byte only involves a `bic` which is to clear the low 2 bits which still belong to `bitfield1`. That code should work unless you are doing something special such as mapping it over memory which produces different result when read, e.g. MMIO or similar. (Note that the code is using read-modify-write.)

Comment: @Jester I am doing flash programming on a microcontroller. Therefore, the code is saved in RAM. Does it make any effect?

Comment: I don't understand the compiler's behaviour, but it looks strange to me to have an `uint64_t` bitfield in an `aligned(4)` structure. Have you tried `aligned(8)`? Or `uint32_t` bitfields? (And BTW, is this 32-bit or 64-bit ARM?)

Comment: @TonyK I tried both, same result.

Comment: note that this is illegal/improper use of a union/struct.  Despite the wild success folks have had with this fad, expect it to fail at some point and the code that uses it require replacement.  It is in the implementation defined area of the language as thus whatever success you are having is because the way the toolchain you are using has implemented it.   masks and shifts which is what this code will produce.

Comment: Also packing structs leads to alignment issues and similar amounts of repair maintenance down the line.  sometimes you get lucky and the product fails before the code does, or you leave the company before the code fails, but sometimes not.

Comment: third, never use structs across compile domains, another portability and maintenance headache.

Comment: looking at the answer this is yet another reason to avoid using structs across compile domains particularly with hardware registers.  you dont get the transfer size you ask for.  pointers have the same problem without being a struct/union pointer, if the processor requires a transfer size, use assembly language to insure it so that you dont have to later maintain that code/interface.  Having an abstracted interface layer has many other features that can save your a$$ down the line, or make your job much easier developing, testing, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I get it. The compiler is using `strb` twice to write the two least significant bytes to a Special Function Register. But the hardware is performing a word write (presumably 32 bits) each time, because byte writes to Special Function Registers are unsupported. No wonder it doesn't work!

As to how you can fix this, that depends on your compiler, and how much it knows about SFRs. As a quick and dirty fix, you can just use bit manipulation on `R`; instead of

```
GROUP.myRegister.B.bitfield1 = 0x60;
```

use e.g.

```
GROUP.myRegister.R = (GROUP.myRegister.R & ~0x3FF) | 0x60;
```

PS Another possibility: it looks like you have turned off optimisation (I see a redundant `ldrb r2,[r3,#00]` instruction in there). Perhaps if you turn it on, the compiler will come to its senses? Worth a try...

PPS Please change `uint64_t` to `uint32_t`. It's making my teeth hurt!

PPPS Come to think of it, that `packed` may be throwing the compiler off, causing it to assume that the bitfield struct may not be word-aligned (and thus forcing byte-by-byte acesss). Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Removing `__attribute__((packed))` solved the problem. Thank you!